# how to extend and modifier a class in different package java -- explained inside

Tags: java

i need to modifier a method from in a class from different package

package structure

AndroidApp ---

```
         -- dependencies " materialSheetFab"
```

materialSheetFab ---

```
               -- src
                  ...
                     --MaterialSheetAnimation.class

                  ---MaterialSheetFab
```

under the `materialSheetAnimation` , i need to overide

```
public void alignSheetWithFab(View fab) {
    ....

    if (rightDiff != 0) { // need to remove this block of code 
        .....
    }
```

the method is called in `MaterialSheetFab`

```
protected void morphIntoSheet(final AnimationListener endListener) {

    // Align sheet's position with FAB
    sheetAnimation.alignSheetWithFab(fab);
```

the problem is member variable in the `materialsheetAnimation` are private so

```
public class Sample extend MaterialSheetAnimat{
  ......
  @overide 
  public void AlignSheetWithFab(Fab){
     ....
     //remove code 
     // but cant call any instance variable  there all private 
     // sheet is private member // sheet.setX(fab.coord[0]; not possible
```

even extending the class doesnt allow me to rewrite the code block am intereested in

Answer (score 0):

> Bbut the problem is member variable in the materialsheetAnimation are private so even extending the class doesnt allow me to rewrite the code block am intereested in

It's the definition of a `private` member, you can't override it.